# About Toggle with same Class Javascript No jQuery

Tags: javascript

**Somebody please help Me!**
I want use a (*JavaScript not JQuery)* by using same a class to Change/hide a style like Toggle on JQuery

```css
.green { color:white; background:green; }

.blue { color:white; background:blue; width:1000px; height:300px; font-size:30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a  class="my-class">Get Details1  </a><br>
<a  class="my-class">Get Details2  </a><br>
<a  class="my-class">Get Details3   </a><br>
<a  class="my-class">Get Details4  </a><br>
<div class="green">
Text <br>
Text <br>
Text <br>
<a  class="my-class">X Close X </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.my-class').click(function(){
  $('.green').toggleClass('blue')  });  });
</script>
```

**I try to change to something like this:** *And it doesn't work like jQuery*
**My Demo (JavaScript(pure JS)):** https://jsfiddle.net/packy/egfcyznm/14/ or ⇓

```js
document.querySelector('.my-class').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('green')[0]
    .classList.toggle('blue');
  }
```

```css
.green {
  color: white;
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a class="my-class">Get Details 1  </a><br>
<a class="my-class">Get Details 2 -- I can't click </a><br>
<a class="my-class">Get Details 3 -- I can't click  </a><br>
<a class="my-class">Get Details 4 -- I can't click   </a><br>
<div class="green">
  Text <br> Text <br> Text <br>
  <a class="my-class">X Close X  -- I can't click  </a>
</div>
```

Get Details 1 <-- i want it to be can click 
Get Details 2 <-- i want it to be can click 
Get Details 3 <-- i want it to be can click 
Get Details 4 <-- i want it to be can click 
X Close X <-- i want it to be can click

**Thanks**

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns the first element that matches the selector. You need to add the listener to all elements returned by `document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns first match found.

You need to loop over whole collection returned by [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and add listener to each instance

jQuery does all this looping for you internally

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // can use querySelector here for first one
        document.querySelector('.green').classList.toggle('blue');         
    });
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: white;
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a class="my-class">Get Details 1  </a><br>
<a class="my-class">Get Details 2 -- I can't click </a><br>
<a class="my-class">Get Details 3 -- I can't click  </a><br>
<a class="my-class">Get Details 4 -- I can't click   </a><br>
<div class="green">
  Text <br> Text <br> Text <br>
  <a class="my-class">X Close X  -- I can't click  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed querySelector for querySelectorAll, so i can get every element wuth my-class on it, then with a foreach loop create the handler so it does what you wanted to..

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.my-class').forEach(function(x){
      x.onclick=function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('green')[0]
        .classList.toggle('blue');
      }
});
```

```css
    .green {
      color: white;
      background: green;
    }

    .blue {
      color: white;
      background: blue !important;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 300px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <a class="my-class">Get Details 1  </a><br>
    <a class="my-class">Get Details 2 -- I can't click </a><br>
    <a class="my-class">Get Details 3 -- I can't click  </a><br>
    <a class="my-class">Get Details 4 -- I can't click   </a><br>
    <div class="green">
      Text <br> Text <br> Text <br>
      <a class="my-class">X Close X  -- I can't click  </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think breaking out the `querySelectors` makes it easier to read, especially when used in conjunction with descriptive names. Otherwise I think what @charlietfl is the best.

```
const myClass = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')
const listText = document.querySelector('.green')

Array.from(myClass).forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        listText.classList.toggle('blue');         
      });
});
```